# Time conversion from string in golang

Tags: time, go

I'm trying to convert a time/date crawled from a NOAA observation from UTC to Pacific Time. The raw data is formatted as a fixed width space delimited string that I convert into an array of strings via strings.Field.

The raw data looks like:

```
2015 11 11 16 50
```

It is stored as:

```
data[0:5]
```

Note that `data` has additional observations that are used elsewhere in the program. How can this be converted to Pacific time such that it will be correct year round, including daylight savings changes? I would eventually like to print it out in RFC822 format (i.e. "02 Jan 06 15:04 PST").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can parse your raw data directly to a time in UTC using time.Parse and Go's reference time (https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants), and then load a PST location and convert the time to that location. It can then be formatted as you wish, e.g.:

```
func main() {
    t, err := time.Parse("2006 01 02 15 04", "2015 11 11 16 50")
    fmt.Println(t, err)

    loc, err := time.LoadLocation("America/Los_Angeles")
    fmt.Println(loc, err)

    t = t.In(loc)
    fmt.Println(t.Format(time.RFC822))
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/mIXxVhmkDB